# How to Pass Variable from Shared Object (.so or .dll) to NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, c, shared-libraries, ffi

It's working with functions by using [node-ffi-napi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi-napi). However, I couldn't find the way to pass variable from shared object (or DLL in Windows term) to NodeJS.

As example, here's my C code:

```c
// mylibrary.h

extern int example;
```

```c
// mylibrary.c

#include <mylibrary.h>

int example = 10;
```

Then I compile it as linux shared object with file name `mylibrary.so`. This is the NodeJS script:

```js
const ffi = require("ffi-napi");

const mylibrary = ffi.Library(
    "./mylibrary.so",
    {
        example: [/* What should I do here? */]
    }
);

console.log("Example variable is", mylibrary.example);
```

Any idea how to do it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Have you been through the tutorial: https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial?

Comment: @jfriend00 Already learnt that documentation. But still, there is no guide to actually pass the variable. Only functions.

Comment: I don't think you're understand what's there.  The part that starts with `var MyLibrary = ffi.Library('libmylibrary', { ...});` appears to be where you teach it what parameters each function takes and then shows you how to call those functions from Javascript.  The C/C++ function definitions and parameters then just need to line up with how you declared them in the `ffi.Library()` statement.  Following that is more on how to declare return values for the C functions.  It looks like it's all there to me.  Did you try all that?

Comment: If you want to share a variable from the shared library, then it's probably best to make a function in the shared library that returns that value.  I don't think you directly access variables like that.

Comment: @jfriend00 So it's impossible to pass the variabel without creating a function on C side?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying.  You can use `ffi-napi` to connect to either your own custom DLLs with your own C-code in them or you can connect to existing DLL entry points that already have an implementation.  Either way, the whole point of this library is to connect to a DLL with a known interface and the ffi-napi library will convert parameters to/from as long as you tell it exactly what the DLL function interface requires.